# Limit of a product of sines

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

The question is:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{r=1}^{2n-2}\{\sin\Bigl(\frac{r\pi}{2n}\Bigr)\}^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

My attempt:

Let $$A=\prod_{r=1}^{2n-2}\{\sin\Bigl(\frac{r\pi}{2n}\Bigr)\}^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \log(A)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{2n-2}\log(\sin\Bigl(\frac{r\pi}{2n}\Bigr))$$

I was thinking of converting this into an integral by

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{2n-2}\log(\sin\Bigl(\frac{r\pi}{2n}\Bigr))\frac{1}{n}$$

Using the limit sum definition of a limit.

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\Bigl(a+\frac{r(b-a)}{n}\Bigr)\frac{b-a}{n}$$

$$\frac{2}{\pi-0}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{2n-2}\log(\sin\Bigl(0+\frac{r(\pi-0)}{2n}\Bigr))\frac{\pi-0}{2n}=^{?}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin x)dx$$

I am not sure how to convert this integral as the bounds of summation are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^{2n-2}\left( \sin \frac{\pi r}{2n}\right)^{1/n}.$$
$$\implies \ln L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{2n-2} \ln \sin\frac{\pi r}{2n}.$$
$let r/n=x$, then $L$ goes over to the integral
$$\ln L=\int_{0}^{2} \ln \sin (\pi x/2)~dx= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \sin z  dz~~~(*)$$
Use  the property that
$$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a/2}[ f(x)+f(a-x)] dx ~~~(1)$$
$$\ln L=\frac{4}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \sin z dz~~~~(2)$$
Next use the property that $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$$
to get $$\ln L=\frac{4}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \cos z dz ~~~(3)$$
Add (2) and (3), to get
$$2 \ln L=\frac{4}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \sin 2z\right) ~dz=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin u~ du-\frac{4}{\pi} \frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 $$
Using (*) here. we write
$$\ln L=-2\ln 2 \implies L=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: What happened to that 2n-2 in the summation bounds? How exactly can you even convert it into an integral using the limit sum definition?

Comment: Yes, take $x-r/n$, the lower limit is $1/n$ and upper limit is $(2n-2)/n$ which are 0 and 2 respectively when $n$ is ber large ($\infty$).

Comment: Could you explain it more formally? I understand how it works intuitively. But I can't understand how to show to formally.

Comment: Usually, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{pn+q} f(r/n) \frac{1}{n} \to \int_{0}^{p} f(x) dx,$ when you take $x=r/n$ the lower limit is $1/n \to 0 $ (as $n \to \infty$) and upper limit is $(pn+q)/n \to p$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Basically, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{p}\sum_{r=(k-1)n+1}^{kn}f(r/n)+\sum_{r=pn+1}^{pn+q}f(x))$=$\sum_{k=1}^{p}\int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)dx+0$?
So as long as 'q' lesser than n, that end part will be effectively zero? In other words if that top bound was $2n-1$ or $2n+5$, the limit summation will all yield the same value?

Comment: Yes, you have got it right, if the lower limit is 90 and  upper limit is $7n+25$ then it will be $\int_{0}^{7} f(x) dx$ as $n\to \infty$.